# Why are interfaces described as "is a", or "is able to" verus "is at least"?

Tags: interface

Now that I've started using interfaces out of need, I finally understand them.

Question, why are the characteristics of an interface described as "is a" or "is able to" versus "is at least a" or "is at least able to".

I think the latter descriptions would have helped me understand better. Does this make sense?

EDIT:
Before grasping interfaces, if I was writing a "Park Activity Generator" application. I would have had a Dog, Frisbee, Adults, Kids, Homeless Person, Bird, Trash etc. My limited/uneducated design thinking was always about how things are different rather than the same. I guess not enough experience to see that identifying the differences, is one exercise - but that identifying the similarities is another(and probably a better first one?). I had no concept of action flexibility, in separating the driver of action from the object.

I believe if my earlier approaches at development weren't so flawed, or I was looking harder, I would have arrived at the traditional explanation earlier, but here is a specific question I posted that sort of describes how I arrived at this "at least a" as what I'm exploring as an organically/stupid-stumbling-along derived need implementation of an interface.

[Is this a sound approach to working with Serialized XML from a 3rd party object that I don't fully understand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112662/is-this-a-sound-approach-to-working-with-serialized-xml-from-a-3rd-party-object-t)

Comment: Because there is no way to please everyone, all of your definitions stem from "is a".. maybe they should have done "is a*"

Comment: Your definitions also work, but so do the existing definitions, and the existing definitions are shorter and snappier. In the IT world shorter _nearly_ always wins e.g. [tl;dr](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLDR)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because when talking about real interface relationships we simply don't speak that way.

A dog IS A runner, or IS ABLE TO run.  (ie Dog implements IRunnable)
vs.
A Human IS AT LEAST A runner, or IS AT LEAST ABLE TO run.

We tend to speak and think in terms of the former over the latter.

Comment: I didn't understand why would want to view a dog as a runner, when it is more than that. A Dog is a runner makes sense, but if someone walked up to me and said that I'd think "he's probably also a barker - so why are you describing one part of a dog to me." Hehe. Now I think I understand, that is allows for classification across different runners. If I was going to write a 3D renderer for a dog running and a person running - in my head I'd think they were so very different, so I would end up with an inflexible 3D renderer before.. not it would be sorta flexible ;)

Comment: Dog implements IRunnable.. lol :) +1

Comment: @user53885 - Yeah, you're on the right track.  The reason we classify a dog as a runner, and a person as a runner, is so that in our code later we can treat dogs and people the same for the purposes of handling running, and leave the details to the individual objects.  You are correct that we could also implement a Speak interface for both dog and person and say both.  A dog IS A runner, and a dog IS A speaker.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "is a" and "is able to" type of language comes from the extensive real-world analogies that the object-oriented community uses. To use a common example, in the real world a teacher is a person and a student is a person, so in the programming world we say instances of the Teacher class are also People. When classifying real-world objects, we don't relate them based on their capabilities. You're right, though, that when programming it can be perfectly natural to say that instances of subclasses of Person have at least the capabilities of a Person, since that is exactly how polymorphism is treated. That's a more imperative sort of approach to the problem, though, and it therefore is probably not as likely to be put forth.

Comment: I'm not proposing it ;) Just exploring why that was my first thought. I couldn't quite grasp interfaces, but I think it had more to do with my uber bad code leading up to trying to grasp :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to think of interfaces as saying something "is a *_*_er" or "is an ___able object"; I disagree with the efforts to replace the "IS" from the description of interfaces with "can" or "has", because the whole point of interfaces is substitutability.  If I have a routine that needs a "sequential data supplier", something that's going to be passed to my routine has to "BE" a "sequential data supplier".  It doesn't have to be a List, or a Queue, or a Stack, or a serial port, or a file, or an array, or any other particular base kind of thing, but it has to "BE" an object that can supply data sequentially in the expected format.

Comment: I understand your routine is agnostic to the greater characteristics of the underlying object, and it makes sense from that perspective. At some point you did stick that interface on your object though, were you thinking "this is a sequential data supplier", or "this is at least/can be a sequential data supplier"? Educationally I think the concept would have helped break me through on understanding. Not suggesting it would help other people, just posting it in case someone else like me is coming at it from the wrong angle.